# How does the WPF Designer know which resource to use?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application without an application.xaml, since I need to do the Main() method by myself. Therefore I neither have an ApplicationDefinition nor an application resource. I currently attach the resource dictionary to the application at the application startup

Of course the WPF Designer complains now about missing resources.

So I want to get rid of two problems:
- I don't want to attach the resource dictionary manually at startup
- I want to get the resources also work at design time in the WPF designer

Is there any help for this problem?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: Well... the obvious solution is to use `App.xaml` - is there a good reason you're not using it?

Comment: The problem is I need to a lot before the app can start up (License Checking, Update Checking, Single Instance, etc. When using Application at startup this is making all things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to use the Main() method for yourself

Just **delete** the following property from the xamlcode of Application.xaml:

```
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
```

Then **add the following** in the code-behind of the Application.xaml:

```
public partial class App : Application
  {

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      // My code goes here, but nothing ever happens.

      base.OnStartup(e);
    }
  }
```

Now you can still use the Application.xaml for your resources and also have your specific startup procedure.

Comment: Hi Basti. I was trying your solution, but nevertheless a Main() is created in the g.cs code. I was more thinking of a solution with an attribute to get rid of the Main() method.